# How to debug the rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using mandril mailer, I have set up my mailers and everything was working fine, at some point the mailer stopped working, I am trying to send a message from the rails console

```
TaskCompletedMailer.client_created(email: 'mymail@gmail.com').deliver
```

I am getting a message in the console that the email has been delivered.

```
[{"email"=>"mymail@gmail.com", "status"=>"sent", "_id"=>"184e03d40a874fa892b5549173ccba80", "reject_reason"=>nil}]
```

but the mail is not been delivered into my account.
How can I debug that ?

Comment: Could you share your mailer configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the logs what can you see there. Probalby the action_mailer config is not correct for your current enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a protocol analyzer, such as Wireshark, to monitor the SMTP traffic on your network card and so check how realy the rails app sends to it.